# Where does Alexa store its music history? Can it be cleared?

Tags: alexa

My Alexa is screwing up: when I play one of Amazon Music's curated music lists, it *always* stops after a set number of songs, prior to the whole list completing. It's as if Alexa only thinks the list is two or three songs long - if I ask for the next song, it says it's at the end of the list.

The thing is - if I play through Amazon music directly, the curated list plays perfectly. And so the list itself is intact. Moreover, it means that Alexa is storing its history separate from Amazon Music's. Sooooo...how do I clear Alexa's music history?